# Why my menu doesn't dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, dropdown

I'm just working on a 'log in'/'sign up' dropdrowing menu for my website, but can't figure out why it isn't working properly.

I'm a beginner in jQuery, so maybe the problem resides in it. Or maybe it has to do with HTMl or CSS, I'm not sure. When I test the page and I open the console, the jQuery doesn't show any error, so I'm not sure about where the problem is. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="navthing">
      <h2><a href="#" id="loginform">Log in</a> | <a href="#">Sign Up</a></h2>
   <div class="login">
    <div class="arrow-up"></div>
     <div class="formholder">
       <div class="randompad">
           <fieldset>
             <label name="email">Email</label>
             <input type="email" value="example@example.com" />
             <label name="password">Password</label>
             <input type="password" />
             <input type="submit" value="Login" />
           </fieldset>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navthing {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.login {
    position: relative;
    width:250px;
    display:none;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #ECF0F1;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
}

.formholder input[type="email"], .formholder input[type="password"] {
  padding: 7px 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 96%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: 0.3s linear;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.formholder input[type="email"]:focus, .formholder input[type="password"]:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #1abc9c;
}
.formholder input[type="submit"] {
  background: #1abc9c;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.formholder input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #1bc6a4;
}

.randompad {
  padding: 10px;
}

.green {
  color: #1abc9c;
}

a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #1abc9c;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').mousedown(function(){
  $(this).css('background', '#2ecc71');
});
$('input[type="submit"]').mouseup(function(){
  $(this).css('background', '#1abc9c');
});

$('#loginform').click(function(){
  $('.login').fadeToggle('slow');
  $(this).toggleClass('green');
});



$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".login");

    if (!container.is(e.target) 
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
        $('#loginform').removeClass('green');
    }
});
```

It shows okay, but doesn't dropdown when I click on 'Log in'. What's wrong? Thank you.

**EDIT 1:** The head of the html page includes those files:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
{% load staticfiles %} 

<title>{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}</title>
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% block style_base %}
<link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
<meta name="description" content="{% block description %}{% endblock %}">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="static/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="static/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="static/js/login3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Here there are both jQuery sources, but I've tried with only one of each with no result. There's a slider also in the website (in main.js) which uses jQuery and works fine.

When I load the page it appears the Log In | Sign Up but nothing happens when I click the 'Log in' button (no dropdown form, nothing).

Comment: It's working https://jsfiddle.net/zgajb4ga/. What is your expected result?

Comment: Have you included the necessary jQuery files ??

Comment: I can see it working on the link... Can't understand it. I've edited the first post with the <head> of my document. The expected result is what happens in your link, just to appear a dropdown form like that in HTML.

Comment: Could it be a problem with some other elements in the same div, or because of z-index or something like that? Can't figure out why isn't the dropdown showing while all the jQuery seems to work fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first part of your jquery code I added this and it worked:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
```

Explanation: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Oh, it was that simple. Thank you!